# Flask on Heroku: unable to use @app.cli.command() decorated functions with heroku cli

Tags: python, heroku, flask, environment-variables

I'm trying to deploy a `Flask` app to `Heroku`. I have a function for initializing my Postgres database wrapped with the `@app.cli.command` decorator so I can execute it with the `Flask` cli tool. This function is very similar to the function for initializing a sqlite database in the `flask` tutorial [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/dbinit/#tutorial-dbinit).

the function works fine on my local machine, but is not working on my `Heroku` deployment:

```
(venv) solomon@prefect trip_test $ heroku run flask initdb
Running flask initdb on ⬢ tripp-exercise... up, run.6637 (Free)
Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Error: No such command "initdb".
```

I read on an older Stack Overflow question that I need to set the `FLASK_APP` environment variable either to the location of my app or to the name of my app. I tried both and neither worked. Here is the commands I used when trying to set FLASK_APP:

```
heroku config:set FLASK_APP=trip_test
heroku config:set FLASK_APP=/app
```

Both of those settings gave the same result ("Error: No such command "initdb".") when I tried to run `heroku run flask initdb`.

Thanks for any suggestions or solutions.

Comment: have you tried flask migrate?? it can help to intitialize database in production also

Comment: Do you have a procfile defined?

Comment: Yes I have a procfile file. However, I just noticed that `gunicorn` is failing with a `ModuleNotFoundError`. My procfile says `web: gunicorn trip_test:app`. `trip_test` is the folder that contains my flask app which is defined in an `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 2):

I Know the answer!: Heroku didn't have $FLASK_APP set in the staging environment's variables. Adding that allowed the command line tool to run. simply go to [https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/your-project/settings](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/api-homolog/settings) and set FLASK_APP to your app after you reveal config vars.